# Parse and Swift getObjectInBackgroundWithId

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I have the following code that continues to show me an error

> Cannot invoke 'getObjectInBackgroundWithId' with an argument list of
>   type '((String), (PFObject!, NSError!) -> Void).

I am trying to allow Swift to randomly choose one of the rows in Parse so that it is random every time.

```
func CallData(){
    GetRandomObjectID()
    if(ObjectIDsPublicArray.count > 0){
        var query : PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "QuestionsandAnswers")
        query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(ObjectIDsPublicArray[RandomID]){
        (ObjectHolder : PFObject!, error : NSError!) -> Void in
            if (error == nil){
                self.Questions = ObjectHolder["Questions"] as! String!
                self.Answers = ObjectHolder["Answers"] as! Array!
                self.Answer = ObjectHolder["Answer"] as! String!
            }
```

Comment: you should check to see if that method take a string as parameter because parse has many thing in the new SDK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like Swift has a problem with forcing a PFObject to exist.  Try making both the object and error optional:

```
(ObjectHolder: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
```